# Summernote toolbar doesn't work when cloned with jQuery

Tags: jquery, summernote, jquery-clone

I have a html template that I use to dynamically creating form fields with summernote.
Once the cloned template is added to the form the tool seems not working properly ?
Can anybody please suggest what I am missing and if any other work around ?

My JS Code is as bellow

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        bookIndex = 0;

        $('.addButton').click(function() {
            bookIndex++;
            var template = $('#bookTemplate'),
                clone    = template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id');
             $('#bookForm').append(clone)                   ;

        });

        $('textarea').summernote();


    });
```

html is :

```
 <form id="bookForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="Title" ></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
        </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
     <div class="form-group" id="bookTemplate">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="Title" ></textarea>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Full code and corresponding output is bellow:
http://jsbin.com/jogema/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but hopefully it will help someone else.

Looks like the problem is that you've already initialized the textarea that you are cloning. Instead you need to copy the template HTML into your code, and then initialize the summernote.

Here's the working js from your jsbin:

```
$(function() {

  $("#add_field_button").click(function (e) {
      var newProd = $('#prod_form_template')
              .clone()
              .removeClass('hide')
              .removeAttr('id')
              .appendTo('#prod_list');
       $('#prod_list').append(newProd);
       $(newProd).summernote();

  });

  $('#prod_list textarea').summernote();

});
```

and jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/xevenisacu/1/edit?html,js,output

**UPDATE**

If you really do need to clone an initialized summernote editor, you can do that too, but you will need to destroy and remove the markup first:

```
// first get rid of the summernote editor

$('#container').find('.summernote').summernote('destroy');

// next remove the extra code created by summernote

$('#container').find('.note-editor').remove();

// finally, remove the summernote element itself

$('#container').find('.summernote').remove();

// clone the template

$('#container').append($('.template.summernote').clone());

// initialize summernote

$('#container').find('.summernote').summernote();
```